# Properly use FormData() in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My ajax call is using FormData but it won't pass through properly saying `TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor is not an object.` but it has no problems with chrome. How can I solve this in firefox? Here's my ajax call.

```
$('#modal_activate_btn, #modal_approve_activate').on("click", function () {

var form = document.querySelector('#editRemovesubmedtypeForm');
var formdata = new FormData(form);

if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'modal_approve_activate' ) {
    parent_id = $(this).val();
    console.log(parent_id);
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/activate_raw_material/' + parent_id,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formdata,
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data == 'exists') {
        $('#ReactivateModal').modal('toggle');
        $('#activateModal').modal('toggle');
    }
    else {
        $('#status_' + data).text('Active').removeClass('label-warning').removeClass('label-danger').addClass('label label-success');
        $('#med_act_'+data).css('display', 'none');
        $('#list_label_refresh_'+data).css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('#activateModal').modal('hide');
    }
}
});
});
```

Comment: what is `form`? `console.log(form)` to find out - it's probably `null` which implies there's no element with `id="editRemovesubmedtypeForm"` - as you've posted no HTML, who knows ... *NOTE: chrome incorrectly allows `new FormData(null);` but Firefox does not*

Comment: To answer how to properly use FormData ... either instantiate FormData with no argument, or an argument that is a `HTMLFormElement` - clearly `document.querySelector('#editRemovesubmedtypeForm');` does not result in what you expect

Comment: Yeah you are right I have concluded on my side that `form` doesn't exist.. Anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) like,

```
 var form = document.querySelector('#editRemovesubmedtypeForm');
 var formdata = $('#editRemovesubmedtypeForm').serialize();
```

Comment: Why would this change the existence of the form - clearly the form does not exist in the question (i.e. `document.querySelector('#editRemovesubmedtypeForm');` returns null)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

```
var formdata = new FormData(form);
```

try

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append(form);
// In the same way you can append more item to formdata
```

and pass this `formdata` in `ajax() data` as you are already using.

Comment: why would `form` magically be something other than `null` as it most likely is in the question?